# how to calculate BIC, score... WITHOUT fit?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I know that thanks to scikit tool, we can calculate BIC or score for Gaussian mixture model as shown below easily.

```
clf.fit(data)
bic=clf.bic(data)
score=clf.score(data)
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html

but my question is, how to calculate bic or score WITHOUT using fit method, when I already have weights, means, covariances and data?

I could set as

```
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type='full')
clf.weights_=weights_list
clf.means_=means_list
clf.covariances_=covariances_list
```

or

```
clf.weights_init=weights_list
clf.means_init=means_list
clf.precisions_init =np.linalg.inv(covariances_list)
```

but when I try to get bic,

```
bic=clf.bic(data)
```

I get error message saying

sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This GaussianMixture instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

I don'T want to run fit, because it will change given weights, means and covariances..
What can i do? 
thanks

Comment: Check out the source code for `bic()` here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py#L722

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set these three variables to pass the check_is_fitted test: `'weights_', 'means_', 'precisions_cholesky_'`. `'weights_'` and `'means_'`, you are setting correctly. And for calculating `'precisions_cholesky_'` you need to have `covariances_` which you do have.

So, just calculate that using [this method here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py#L289)

```
from sklearn.mixture.gaussian_mixture import _compute_precision_cholesky
precisions_cholesky = _compute_precision_cholesky(covariances_list, 'full')
```

Change the "full" to appropriate covariance type and then set the result to clf using

```
clf.precisions_cholesky_ = precisions_cholesky
```

Make sure the shape of all these variables correspond correctly to your data.